# Anet A6-L won't turn on again

Tags: troubleshooting, power-supply, start

I've just assembled my new Anet a6-L (with auto leveling). At first everything goes well, it turned on ready to setup but a couple hours later the printer just shutdown and won't turn on for about an hour. I carefully followed the steps concerning the wiring part (below are some pictures).

[image]

I just don't get it.. The power supply does light up the green LED when connected to power. Could you guys help me?

Comment: Welcome to the stack, but sadly without further info we can't help. What did you do before it stopped and shut down? Does the LED light up or not?

Comment: It is strange that the printer fails and cannot be switched on, usually this hints to overheating of electronic parts. Have you checked for excessive heat of the electronics?

Comment: Have you checked the output of the power supply? Just because the lights are on doesn't mean it's putting out any juice. A multimeter will help you figure this out.